# React Native this.'f_createWallet' is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptojs

```js
import bip39 from 'react-native-bip39';
import bip32 from 'bip32';
import ethUtil from 'ethereumjs-util';
//    import { ethers } from 'ethers';
//    import { randomBytes } from 'react-native-randombytes'


export class CreateWalletScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        mnemonic: null,
        loading: false
    }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    bip39.generateMnemonic().then(mnemonic => {
        this.setState({ mnemonic })
    });
}


_createWallet = async () => {
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(this.state.mnemonic);
  const root = bip32.fromSeedSync(seed);
  const xPrivKey = root.derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0");
  const privKey = xPrivKey.privateKey.toString('hex');
  let address = ethUtil.pubToAddress(xPrivKey.publicKey, true).toString('hex');
  address = ethUtil.toChecksumAddress(address).toString('hex');
  alert(address);
}


    render(){
        return(
        
        ...
        <Button onPress={() => 
        this.createWallet()} />
        ...
        
        )}
```

"react-native-bip39": "^2.3.0",
"bip32": "^2.0.5",

error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awJH4.png)

Since I'm a beginner, I'm making crypto wallet.

Use the bip library.

Pressing the button should display the address.

But I'm in trouble. damn

If you help me, human peace will come.

plz ...

---

new error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXJcB.jpg)

Comment: `this.f_createWallet` -> `this._createWallet`?

Comment: Oh it was a stupid mistake
Function name resolved but new problem
Can you help me?

I'll add the error to the text!
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your function has to have the same name of the call:

```
<Button onPress={() => 
        this._createWallet()} />
```

Comment: Oh it was a stupid mistake
Function name resolved but new problem
Can you help me?

I'll add the error to the text!
Thanks